# How do I load Static UITableView Headers into my app from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: ios, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase firestore database set up to store quiz data for my iOS app. My quiz data is supposed to load into a grouped static table view, with the section header being the question and each cell in the section being an answer choice. My problem is I can not figure out how to load data into the header.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9DRw.jpg

This is what my quiz table view looks like right now. The data loaded in is actually supposed to be where "Header" is.

```
    var quizArray = [Quiz]()
    var db: Firestore!

    let cellId = "cellId"
    let headerId = "headerId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Question"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        tableView.register(AnswerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.register(QuestionHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerId)

        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        db.collection("Quizzes").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {

                        let data = document.data()
                        let header = data["Header"] as? String ?? ""
                        let optionA = data["OptionA"] as? String ?? ""
                        let optionB = data["OptionB"] as? String ?? ""
                        let optionC = data["OptionC"] as? String ?? ""
                        let optionD = data["OptionD"] as? String ?? ""
                        let correctAnswer = data["CorrectAnswer"] as? String ?? ""
                        let newQuiz = Quiz(Header: header, OptionA: optionA, OptionB: optionB, OptionC: optionC, OptionD: optionD, CorrectAnswer: correctAnswer)
                        self.quizArray.append(newQuiz)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return quizArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        let quiz = quizArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(quiz.Header): \(quiz.OptionA): \(quiz.OptionB): \(quiz.OptionC): \(quiz.OptionD): \(quiz.CorrectAnswer)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        return tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let controller = ResultsViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to load in data for the static table view header or should I be looking into another way to format my quiz? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

declare your header xib with this line

```
let questionHeaderView = questionHeader().loadNib() as! questionHeader
```

declare an extension for UIView

```
extension UIView {
/** Loads instance from nib with the same name. */
func loadNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nibName = type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
}}
```

then in viewDidload() function set tableview header after set it attributes

```
 questionHeaderView.textLabel.text = "your text here"
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = questionHeaderView
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the extension to my QuestionHeader.swift class (which I assume is fine?). I added the other two things to my QuestionTableViewController. When I run I am getting a NSInternalInconsistencyError: Could not load nib in bundle 'NSBundle... QuestionHeader". I tried moving the extension to my QuestionTableViewController but that's giving me the same result. Any thoughts?